# Is it possible for POST requests sent sequentially to be received out of order?

Tags: rest

I'm a bit new to restful API usage.

suppose that I am sequentially sending out 1000 post requests in python, is it possible that my server could receive these requests out of order? (for example post request 5 is somehow received before post request 4)

If it is not possible for requests to be handled out of order, how do web application frameworks know what order to handle the requests in? is there some sort of timestamp/metadata that indicates priority of the request? For example, does the oldest request HAVE to be fulfilled as soon as possible?

I am curious because I am using the POST api to populate my database and I noticed that my sequentially sent data NEVER has come out of order. I don't want to be dependent on this assumption that sent data will always be consistently in the proper order, so I thought I should ask here

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending requests and *wait* for a response before sending the next one, then everything will happen in order, guaranteed.

If you are sending many requests in parallel, there's generally no guarantee which will arrive first and get processed first.

It's pretty reasonable to assume that the request that arrives first also gets processed first, and over a local fast network that may usually be the case; but over the internet specific packets can get delayed for lots of reasons. Even wifi might cause one of your requests to have to be resent if it wasn't received well the first time.

tl;dr: the only way you can guarantee order is if you wait for a response before sending the next request.